# How to calculate value with textchanged

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to make some simply calculations with the textchanged function but it doesn't seem to work. So here's what i have.

1.
got cost1 and cost2 from sql

```
cost1.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(36)
cost2.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(38)
totalcost.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(86)
```

The SQL datatypes are decimals.

2.
Insert new values to cost1 and cost2. basically i'm trying to get cost1 + cost2 = totalcost then save it to mysql.

1. adding it in manually into sql is not a problem. the problem is getting totalcost to auto calculate or at least to calculate when i update mysql.

I've made 3 textboxes.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="cost1"  OnTextChanged="cost1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="cost2"  OnTextChanged="cost2_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="totalcost" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>



Private Sub CalculateAll()
totalcost.Text = cost1.Text + cost2.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub cost1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cost1.TextChanged
        Call CalculateAll()
    End Sub

Protected Sub cost2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cost2.TextChanged
        Call CalculateAll()
    End Sub
```

the problem is on text change totalcost becomes 000.000.000.000.00 and whatever i type into cost1 becomes the initial value. Please help. Thanks. If the info is not enough please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Sub should be like below:

```
Private Sub CalculateAll()
    Dim cost_1 As Decimal = 0D
    Dim cost_2 As Decimal = 0D
    Dim total As Decimal = 0D
    Decimal.TryParse(cost1.Text, cost_1)
    Decimal.TryParse(cost2.Text, cost_2)

    total = cost_1 + cost_2
    totalcost.Text = total.ToString()
End Sub
```

**EDIT :**

While saving to Db, you have to convert string to decimal. I would suggest using Parameterized query:

```
    Dim cost_1 As Decimal = 0D
    Dim cost_2 As Decimal = 0D
    Dim total As Decimal = 0D
    Dim id As String = Request.QueryString("id")
    Decimal.TryParse(cost1.Text, cost_1)
    Decimal.TryParse(cost2.Text, cost_2)
    Decimal.TryParse(totalcost.Text, total)

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE tbl_vehiclemanagement SET f_usercosting=@usr, f_allinprice=@totalcost, f_expenses1=@cost1, f_expenses2=@cost2 WHERE f_id=@id"
    cmd.CommandText = sqlquery

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("usr", usr)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("totalcost", totalcost)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cost1", cost1)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cost2", cost2)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id)
    'Open connection and execute the query here
```

**EDIT 2 :**
If you want to restore the textbox's initial values, you can save the values to viewstate and retrieve them on reset.

While retrieving the values in textbox, save them in viewstate also:

```
cost1.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(36)
cost2.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(38)
totalcost.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(86)

' Add these lines to save values in ViewState
ViewState("cost1") = cost1.Text
ViewState("cost2") = cost2.Text
ViewState("totalcost") = totalcost.Text
```

Add a reset button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Reset" OnClick="Reset_Click" runat="server"  Text="Button" />
```

And the buttons event restore text box values. But first check if the viewstate is not null:

```
Protected Sub Reset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Reset.Click

    cost1.Text = "0.00"
    cost2.Text =  "0.00"
    totalcost.Text =  "0.00"

    If (ViewState("cost1")) IsNot Nothing Then cost1.Text = ViewState("cost1").ToString()
    If (ViewState("cost2")) IsNot Nothing Then cost2.Text = ViewState("cost2").ToString()
    If (ViewState("totalcost")) IsNot Nothing Then totalcost.Text = ViewState("totalcost").ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved half my problem. now it's showing 1.00 when it's added. but when i update my sql database it says System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +700510
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +114
[InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "UPDATE tbl_vehiclemanagement SET" to type 'Double' is not valid.]

Comment: Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE tbl_vehiclemanagement SET f_usercosting='" + usr + "', f_allinprice='" + totalcost + "', f_expenses1='" + cost1 + "', f_expenses2='" + cost2 + "' WHERE f_id=" & Request.QueryString("id")

Comment: if it helps, I've actually changed the datatype in mysql to decimal(11,2)

Comment: Trying to guess how you're saving the data. Please see the updated answer. To prevent sql injection, parameterized query is used.

Comment: Strange thing is without the calculations it goes straight through. eg. cost3 has no calculations to it. using the same method, i can update it into my database. but after i do the dim cost_3 as decimal =0D, it no longer allows it.. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I've solved it! All i did was dim cost1 as string and it worked. Now my only problem is i'm guessing with the autopostback function. because whenever i try to change the value of cost1 or cost2, it reverts to it's original value (eg. from is stored in database) Any ideas? Thanks Alot

Comment: My guess is you are populating the textboxes in Page_Load. Just wrap the code block in `If Not IsPostBack Then ... EndIf`.

Comment: Worked. Thanks! one more question, how do i make a button with the reset function? previously it was ok because of the postback. now it does nothing.

Comment: Add a buttton and double click to open click method in code. Set Text of the controls to "" like: cost1.text = ""   cost2.Text = ""  totalcost.Text = ""  ... I can't add linebreak in comment :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That changes the textbox to (empty). Is there a way to change it back to it's initial value?(meaning the value loaded from mysql) The only way i can think of is calling it back from the database. eg. (cost1.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(36)) Thanks !

Comment: You want to restore the values of those two text boxes - I would rather save them in viewstate or session or hiddenfield rather than hitting database again. I am editing my answer to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I dont really understand edit2. "if viewstate isnot nothing"? shouldnt it be if viewstate is nothing? Thanks.. also am i correct to assume that there is no way to reset the form to it's initial value just by clicking the "reset" button?

Comment: or do you mean adding the if viewstate lines to button 2? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I have added the code to Reset button's event. `if viewstate isnot nothing` is to check if the viewstate is not null. If it is null. ToString() will cause null reference exception.

Comment: Works very well. Thanks alot for all the help! kinda new to all this. is it possible to ask you a few more questions not relating to this question? Thanks

Comment: Feel free to email me if you have any questions. Unrelated questions are not welcomed in SO :-)

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
Protected Sub cost1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cost1.TextChanged

        If cost2.text = Nothing Then
         'add code here if you want
        Else    
         Call CalculateAll()
        End if

End Sub

Protected Sub cost2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cost2.TextChanged

         If cost1.text = Nothing Then
            'add code here if you want
         Else
            Call CalculateAll()
         End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with that because I've set the default as 0.00 therefore the calculations I'm getting is cost1 = 1.00 cost2 = 0.00 and total cost is 1.000.00 somehow it just added it behind instead of being 1.00.... Any other ideas? Thanks